# Secret is not listed when viewing the Service Account

Tags: kubernetes

I have created the following objects in my `minikube` setup

- ServiceAccount
- Secret
- Role
- RoleBinding

When I try try to get the ServiceAccount using `kubectl get sa`, I get the following output:

```
➜  ~ k get sa
NAME      SECRETS   AGE
...
test      0         4m13s
```

And it says `0` secrets. Here is how I imperatively created the above objects

```
kubectl create sa test
```

```
➜  ~ kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: test
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/service-account.name: test
type: kubernetes.io/service-account-token
EOF
```

```
kubectl create role test --verb=create,get,list,watch --resource=pods,jobs
```

```
kubectl create rolebinding test --role=test --serviceaccount=default:test
```

can someone help me understand why it is not showing?

Thank you!